# How to listen to the event that a visual is selected?

Tags: powerbi-embedded

When a visual is selected (by mouse or keyboard), the Visualizations pane will highlight the visual type icon and list the things related to the selected visual.

How do I implement such functionality?

Checking each visual.isActive() in active page is not an option, because you don't know when to check, and the html element (used for embedding) click/change event is not propagated through.

Tried buttonClicked, dataSelected events, they are not right.

https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Handling-Events

Is this supported or not?

Comment: If you do not succeed here, put the question in the following link: https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4):

Listening to the event of selection of visuals is not currently supported in Power BI Embedded. The objects on which the events are supported currently are reports, dashboards, and tiles.

However, you can get the visuals of specific page using this code.

```
report.on("loaded", function() {
    report.getPages()
        .then(function(pages) {
            // Retrieve first page.
            var firstPage = pages[0];
            firstPage.getVisuals()
                .then(function(visuals) {
                       console.log(visuals); // It will give you the list of visuals of the current page
                 })
        })
});
```

You can also listen to the tileClicked event for the dashboards, as it will give you tile-specific information.

```
tile.on("tileClicked", function (event) {
    Log.logText("Tile clicked event");
    Log.log(event.detail);
});
```

Please refer : https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Handling-Events